# How to detect who visit my website from instagram

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I created a website with php and put my websites link in my instagram biography. How can i detect which instagram account visit my website from my instagram biography?

Comment: What you're asking isn't really possible. Modern browsers restrict how they use the `Referer` (sic) HTTP header, and Facebook/Meta/Instagram goes to a lot of trouble to keep Instagram's users silod.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to track which user has visited, yet we can gather some analytics like clicks on your website using `Google Analytics`. You can create `Events` in that and trigger them after some time(like 3-5sec).On the GA Dashboard then you can see these analytics. Similarly you can gather other informatics.

This is basically related to your web functionalities, getting info of instagram user however I think it's not possible as far as i know.